# Figma-like auto text resize option in Adobe products Photoshop, Illustrator etc

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, figma

Is there a function, to automatically resize text box to the test itself like Figma has?

- when I click two times on this little icon on the bottom of the textbox, it somehow resizes it, but leaves some area between the box and margin of a text. It doesn't go all the way
- it doesn't move the sides of the textbox
- options for Type-> area type options-> AutoSize & Preferences-> text-> Auto Size New Area Type, does not really do anything that would change this or I didn't noticed it and it works precisely that way?
  (but I think it doesn't, the second option just lets the program to add another line not hide it after reaching the limit of the textbox

[image]